# Swift project with Travis CI

Tags: swift, xcode7, yaml, travis-ci

I'm trying to set my Swift project up with Travis CI, but i keep getting this error.

[image]

Here is my YAML file.

```
language: objective-c  #1
xcode_project: Tjenesto.xcodeproj #3
xcode_scheme: Tjenesto #4
xcode_sdk: iphonesimulator8.4 #5
```

I'm using this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/109418/travis-ci-tutorial

Answer (score 0):

#### Non ASCII characters?

Error seems to be at line 1 column 1, i.e. the very first character of your script

#### Specify an Xcode image

Not directly related, but you are leaving Xcode open to [Travis CI interpretation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/osx-ci-environment/#OS-X-Version):

```
osx_image: xcode8.3
```

And when using Xcode 8, you may need to visit [this Stack Overflow quesion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41786984).